# What goes in a Stack package.yaml file?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I notice that Stack supports using a `package.yaml` file that it will use to generate a `.cabal` file. For example, [yi-core/package.yaml](https://github.com/yi-editor/yi/blob/2f0c7b738b3a1f79ff149034db2c4392273ee26f/yi-core/package.yaml). Its structure seems very similar to a Cabal file, but not quite the same. Some of the keys have been renamed (for example, Stack uses `source-dirs` instead of `hs-source-dirs`).

I haven't found any documentation on this feature. [The Stack docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/) don't seem to mention `package.yaml` at all. Does a specification exist?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is hpack, available here: https://github.com/sol/hpack

It's a slightly different package format, and, as you say, can be used to generate cabal files. It isn't directly tied to stack.

Comment: Thanks. I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2750) to Stack to mention this in the docs.