# Stack's package.yaml vs stack.yaml

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

[Stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack) has supported [hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack)'s `package.yaml` configuration files since at least around [this commit](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/commit/ee043bc54a316661cc207672f501cfdcef468a69), as far as I can tell, but there's not much documentation about the differences between it and the `stack.yaml` file.

One of the few links I've found talking about it is [this documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/stack_yaml_vs_cabal_package_file/), where it says:

> `package.yaml` is a file format supported by hpack. It adds some niceties on top of cabal. For example, hpack has YAML syntax support and will automatically generate of `exposed-modules` lists. However, it's just a frontend to cabal package files.

So from this, it seems like `package.yaml` provides a superset of the `*.cabal` file's configuration ability, like the `stack.yaml` file also does.

---

The [documentation here](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#inner-workings-of-stack) implies `stack.yaml` is the configuration file:

> Next, let's look at our stack.yaml file, which gives our project-level settings.

...[and later says](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#adding-dependencies) that `package.yaml` is for storing dependencies:

> To tell stack to use `text`, you need to add it to your `package.yaml` file — specifically in your dependencies section...

There's [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332040/what-goes-in-a-stack-package-yaml-file), but it sadly doesn't clarify the difference between the two files.

I've been using `package.yaml` for all my project's configurations, and never using `stack.yaml`.

---

So, what is the relationship between stack's `package.yaml` and `stack.yaml` files? If/when their responsibilities overlap, which is it better practice to use?

Comment: Do you use `stack`? Can `stack build` really succeed without a `stack.yaml`?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Just checked and it can't build without a `stack.yaml`, but the only things in the file (that was generated by stack 1.6.5) are a `resolver` and a `packages` tag - everything else is in the `package.yaml`. I can even comment out the `packages` tag and the build runs fine.

Comment: Do you understand what the difference between the `package-name.cabal` and `stack.yaml` is? `package.yaml` serves as an alternative for the cabal file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> So from this, it seems like `package.yaml` provides a superset of the `*.cabal` file's configuration ability, like the `stack.yaml` file also does.

`stack.yaml` does not provide a superset of `*.cabal` configurations.

---

The `*.cabal` file is the package-level configuration. It can be generated by `hpack` from a `package.yaml`. This configuration provides essential information about the package: dependencies, exported components (libraries, executables, test suites), and settings for the build process (preprocessors, custom `Setup.hs`). Many projects also don't use `hpack` and don't have a `package.yaml`, only a `*.cabal` file.

The `stack.yaml` file is the project-level configuration, which specifies a particular environment to make a build reproducible, pinning versions of compiler and dependencies. This is usually specified by a resolver (such as `lts-11.4`).

`stack.yaml` is not redundant with `package.yaml`. `package.yaml` specifies what dependencies are needed. `stack.yaml` indicates one way to consistently resolve dependencies (specific package version, and/or where to get it from, for example: on Hackage, a remote repository, or a local directory).

`stack.yaml` is most useful to developers: we don't want our build to suddenly break because a dependency upgraded while working on another project, hence we pin everything with `stack.yaml`. This file is less useful to users, who may have external constraints (typically, versions are already fixed by some distribution).

- In many cases, just specifying the resolver in `stack.yaml` is enough. Hence new `stack` users usually don't need to worry about configuring `stack.yaml`.
- A resolver specifies a curated set of packages with specific versions (the standard ones are listed on stackage.org). If a dependency of the package is missing from the chosen resolver, then it must be listed in the `extra-deps` field of `stack.yaml`.
- A project can span multiple packages, that thus get added to the `packages` field of `stack.yaml`, so they can be built in a single common environment and depend on each other.
- Another common use case is to create many `stack.yaml` (with different names) to easily test various configurations (e.g., GHC versions or package flags).

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice answer - just to clarify: would you only need to put a dependency in `stack.yaml` if you require its version to be pinned? Whereas putting it in `package.yaml` lets the resolver pick a version?

Comment: The stack.yaml actually specifies versions for all packages. Most of them are usually implicit in the choice of resolver. There are resolvers with no packages (`ghc-*`), with which every single dependency, including transitive ones, need to be listed as extra-deps.

Comment: @hnefatl An entry in `extra-deps` is only required if a dependency is not contained in a resolver, or if you want to have a specific version. Note that packages and versions contained in a resolver are expected to not change, and as far as I know `stack` will cache the resolver's data. On the other hand, dependencies in `*.cabal` and `package.yaml` should be soft, lest one loses the ability to make a version compatible to multiple resolvers.

Comment: Maybe it's a bit late to comment, but: I think it should also be noted that `package.yaml` is not mandatory in any way - it's just a thin layer over the `*.cabal` file, and many people (including me) choose to edit the `*.cabal` file directly.

Comment: "Another common use case is to create many stack.yaml (with different names) to easily test various configurations (e.g., GHC versions or package flags)." @Li-yaoXia do you know a place where there are some examples of what you say ?

Comment: One place is to look for files like `stack-lts*.yaml` on Github: https://github.com/search?p=1&q=filename%3Astack-lts*.yaml&type=Code I know aeson has a bunch of stack  files in its root, I'm not sure whether they are still used, but that's where I first picked it up.