# Stack.yaml vs package.yaml for adding dependencies

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Possibly a dumb question:

The [Stack documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#stacks-functions) mentions `package.yaml` as the right place to add dependencies, but all I see in my project directory is a single `stack.yaml` file; is that the right place, then?

(I see an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774055/stacks-package-yaml-vs-stack-yaml) that asks about redundancy between these two files, but I don't even see the `package.yaml` file at all !!)

If it helps:

```
$ stack --version
Version 1.9.3, Git revision 40cf7b37526b86d1676da82167ea8758a854953b (6211 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.31.1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*package.yaml* is actually processed by **hpack**; it's not a **stack** feature, except in so far as if it sees one there in your project it'll use it and generate a *.cabal* file.

You can create a *package.yaml* yourself from scratch. You don't need to do `stack new` or whatever.

I certainly find it using *package.yaml* rather than *project.cabal* convenient. There's no nice user guide, as such (as pointed out in the **hpack** [README](https://github.com/sol/hpack#readme)) but a few examples and you'll realize there's not much to it:

- https://github.com/oprdyn/publish/blob/master/package.yaml
- https://github.com/oprdyn/docker.haskell/blob/master/files/src/baseline/package.yaml

I have seen a few mentions that the **Cabal** library now supports new features to reduce the tedious repetition (perhaps in a `>= 2.x` format?) which might make the need for *package.yaml* go away fairly soon, which would be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Usually `package.yaml` is the correct place to add dependencies, and `stack.yaml` is the correct place to add additional information about those dependencies.

If you're just using packages from the project's main stack snapshot and using the default build settings for all of them: you generally don't need to edit `stack.yaml` at all. Dependencies are mentioned in `stack.yaml` when:

- The package isn't in a stack snapshot
- You need a different version of the package from the one your stack snapshot provides
- The package (or the specific version you need) isn't on hackage at all (for example: you need stack to get it from github)
- You need the package to be compiled with non-default flags
- etc

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, it turns out I had run `stack new <project> simple`; if I had run `stack new <project> new-project`, it would have generated the `package.yaml` file instead of the `<project>.cabal` file I currently find there.